# Check values in a form (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I've five variables in a form, for simplicity I named them A, B, C, D and E.
In order to submit the form (A or (B or C)) and (D or E) must have a value (I hope it's clear :P).
I've tried with

```
if ((A == "" || (B == "" || C == "")) && (D == "" || E == "")) {
    alert ("Error!");
} else {
    form.submit();
}
```

But it doesn't work in every case. For example, if A, B and C have a value, the form is submitted even if neither D or E have values.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: you are missing a `{`

Comment: I am thinking your or logic is wrong.... Thinking you want some ANDs and not ORs.

Comment: If you're using this code to validate a form you should consider trimming the string value and then checking if the length is greater than 0 (or compare it against an empty string like you're doing). This way a user can't enter a bunch of blank spaces to circumvent your validation. Unless you're already formatting the values before you store them in `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have all strings, you could just reverse the condition and check all  with logical AND and one OR.

```js
var a = '', b = '', c = '', d = '', e = '';
    
if (a && b && c || d && e) {
    console.log('form.submit();');
} else {
    console.log('Error!');
}
```

> Why it works:
>
> given
>
> ```
> (A == "" || (B == "" || C == "")) && (D == "" || E == "")
> ```
>
> simplified `A == ""` is equivalent to `!A`
>
> ```
> (A == "" || B == "" || C == "") && (D == "" || E == "")
>
> (!A || !B || !C) && (!D || !E)
> ```
>
> [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!(a && b) = !a || !b` or `!(a || b) = !a && !b`
>
> ```
>  (!A || !B || !C) && (!D || !E)
>
>  !(A &&  B &&  C) && !(D &&  E)
>
> !((A &&  B &&  C) ||  (D &&  E))
> ```
>
> operator precedence
>
> ```
> !(A && B && C || D && E)
> ```
>
> now switch/negate then <-> else
>
> ```
> A && B && C || D && E
> ```

Comment: That's the not the logic that the OP has provided.

Comment: actually its the same logic, just negated.

Comment: So you don't need the parenthesis with AND in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic to:

```
if ((A != "" || (B != "" || C != ""))
    && (D != "" || E != "")) {
        form.submit();
} else {
       alert ("Error!");
}
```

The alternative is to do it like so:

```
if ((A == "" && (B == "" && C == ""))
    || (D == "" && E == "")) {
        alert ("Error!");
} else {
      form.submit();
}
```

**Edit: the first snippet can be refactored to the following:**

```
if ((A || (B || C )) && (D || E )) {
        form.submit();
} else {
       alert ("Error!");
}
```

And the same can be done with the second snippet with the NOT operator `!`.

Comment: `alert ("Error!");`

Comment: The only thing I'd add would be instead of using the == operator use the === operator, this checks value and type, unless type doesn't matter.  Another discussion, but should be considered.

Comment: @DylanWright, the variables are guaranteed to be strings, since they are input values.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (A == "" || B == "" || C == "" && (D == "" || E == "")) {
        alert ("Error!");
} else {
       form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code a bit. I think this should work for you.

```js
function isNonEmpty(string) {
  //returning the string's truthiness value
  return string.trim() ? true : false;
}

//change these values around to make sure the logic is correct
var A = "cat",
  B = "    ",
  C = "dog",
  D = "",
  E = " turtle";

//almost exactly what you have just calling a function for neatness
if ((isNonEmpty(A) || isNonEmpty(B) || isNonEmpty(C)) &&
  (isNonEmpty(D) || isNonEmpty(E))) {
  console.log("Valid form. Time to submit!");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid form. Please check your values!");
}
```